# Using scipy.optimize to implement a neural network with back propagation

Tags: optimization, python, machine-learning

My problem is something similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10258094/correct-usage-of-scipy-optimize-fmin-bfgs).

I'm trying to implement a (Neural Network) Cost function, Back propogation algorithm in Python.

The Neural Network has 3 layers. Hence 2 parameters to optimize (Theta1 and Theta2; depicted as T1 and T2 in the program).

I tried the solution offered in above link, but doesn't work for me.

my Cost Function is defined with following parameters.

```
def CostFunction(Thetas, X, y, Lambda = None):

    T1 = Thetas[0]
    T2 = Thetas[1]

    if(Lambda == None):
        Lambda = 0
    
    m = X.shape[0]
    # so on.......
    return J, [Theta1_grad, Theta2_grad]
```

How would I optimize the above function using `Scipy.optimize.fmin_bfgs`?

I have the following code, doesn't seem to work:

```
initial_values = np.zeros([0]))
myargs = (Thetas ,X, y)
def decorated_cost(Thetas):
    return NeuralNetwork.CostFunction(Thetas, X, y, Lambda=1)
print scipy.optimize.fmin_bfgs(decorated_cost, Thetas , maxiter=400)
```

I need to optimize both Theta1 and Theta2 but the API only takes 1 parameter as input.

Also, for some reason the above code (after a couple of iterations) the order of parameters of input to Cost function seem to change when operated by optimize function.

Comment: yes. I'm trying to minimize Theta1, Theta2 so that entire cost returned (depicted as "J" in the program) is reduced.

Comment: I tried fixing the parameters, but it keep getting the following eror TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'tuple' and 'tuple'

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'tuple' and 'tuple'

Comment: initial values should not be zeros in an Neural Network training algorithm. My initial values set for the program are 2 values of Thetas (randomly initialized). Scipy optimize function runs for a couple of arguments and stops. Giving some error in function "approx_fprime" defined inside scipy.optimize module

Comment: this question has some answers on [reddit](http://www.reddit.com/r/MachineLearning/comments/113mjw/using_scipyoptimize_to_optimize_a_cost_function).  We'd be happy to take it on scicomp.se.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The objective function should return only the cost value, not the gradient.  Something like this:

```
def decorated_cost(Thetas, X, y, Lambda):
    return NeuralNetwork.CostFunction(Thetas, X, y, Lambda=Lambda)[0]

initial_values = np.array([0.1, 0.2])
print scipy.optimize.fmin_bfgs(decorated_cost, initial_values, maxiter=400, args=(X, y, 1))
```

Note that I added `[0]` after the call to `CostFunction` in `decorated_cost`.

You could also do something like this:

```
def decorated_cost(Thetas, X, y, Lambda):
    return NeuralNetwork.CostFunction(Thetas, X, y, Lambda=Lambda)[0]

def decorated_gradient(Thetas, X, y, Lambda):
    return NeuralNetwork.CostFunction(Thetas, X, y, Lambda=Lambda)[1]

initial_values = np.array([0.1, 0.2])
print scipy.optimize.fmin_bfgs(decorated_cost, initial_values, maxiter=400, args=(X, y, 1), fprime=decorated_gradient)
```

but that is inefficient.  Instead `CostFunction` should be split into two functions, one for the objective function and one for the gradient.